# What is needed to have the right to close a question (as a duplicate) with a single vote?

Tags: discussion, closing, moderators, privileges, dupehammer

I've noticed that some questions are closed by a single vote. What's needed to give an user such a privilege?

Comment: Moderators can do that.

Comment: @GEdgar Not only!

Comment: You want superpowers? look at the rules in this [answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254590/2297725).

Comment: @achillehui I love to have superpowers! (To be serious, I think some questions need a more specialized perspective to be perceived as duplicates and I'd be happy if I could close them as such; an example is [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111944/ring-of-fractions-of-a-noetherian-ring-with-zero-nilradical) which collected three closing votes and stopped.)

Comment: I have added some tags to the question which seemed reasonable to me. Of course, if you disagree or can choose a better set of tags, please, do edit them.

Comment: Good luck in your hunt for this privilege! Use it wisely, once you get it.

Comment: Sorry about the strange timing of this comment. I just stumbled upon this thread. For what it's worth, I think you are using your commutative-algebra dupehammer wisely. Which is what I expected to happen once you reach the threshold.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A non-moderator user can cast a binding duplicate vote if they have a gold-badge in a tag originally on the question (and the usual criteria for dupe-closure are met). Note that these users are marked on these occassions with the symbol for a gold badge, a yellow circle.

To get a golden tag-badge one must have a total score of 1000 in at least 200 non-community wiki answers with this badge; the score is the number of upvotes (minus down-votes) a post gets. To track one progress one can look at the [list of tags on ones user-page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=tags).

See posts tagged [dupehammer](/questions/tagged/dupehammer) for earlier discussion.

Comment: Thanks. And how is gained such a gold badge?

Comment: You are welcome. To get a gold tag badge "You must have a total score of 1000 in at least 200 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge." Note it is score, not points. Generally, you can find descriptions of all badges on http://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges

Comment: Thanks again! (What's the difference between "score" and "points"?)

Comment: "Score" is net-votes (upvotes minus downvotes). Points is $10\cdot \text{upvotes} - 2\cdot \text{downvotes}$, ignoring accepts, @user26857.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks. (Is my score in the commutative-algebra section equal to 519 as it's written in a small grey box in my profile?)

Comment: @user26857 It was when it was last updated (some time early today [UTC]; it's updated daily), now it may be slightly higher or lower, depending on what votes your non-community-wiki answers in that tag have received since then. If you hover your mouse over the grey box, a tooltip with a breakdown and short explanation of the data shows up.

Comment: @DanielFischer Got it! Thanks again!